# SQL: Count with group by problems

Tags: mysql

I have problem with my script - what I need?

I have this table :

```
--------------------------------
| id | ip            | country |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 80.100.100.20 | CZ      |
--------------------------------
| 2  | 80.100.100.20 | CZ      |
--------------------------------
| 3  | 90.900.900.90 | CZ      |
--------------------------------
| 4  | 55.555.555.55 | RU      |
--------------------------------
```

This is my table with "visitors" so I need get count of visitors from countries. In this case I need:

```
2 CZ
1 RU
```

Rows with country = CZ is 3, but 2 have same IP address, so real visitors are 2.

How can i do it? Thanks.

I'm trying some like this:

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `count`, `country` 
FROM `1799_visitors` 
GROUP BY `ip`
```

Returns:

```
1 CZ
1 CZ
1 RU
```

It's probably good, but I need sum of them.

```
2 CZ
1 RU
```

It's probably solved by this solution:

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `count`, `country` 
FROM `1799_visitors` 
GROUP BY `country`
```

But in another way, I need also count of all counts, like this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `count`, `country` 
FROM `1799_visitors` 
GROUP BY `country`
```

Results:

```
CZ 2
RU 1
```

I need visitors = 3, i'm thinking about this, but I do not want use 2 select, do you have another solution for me?

```
SELECT SUM(count) FROM (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT  `ip` ) AS  `count` ,  `country` 
FROM  `1799_visitors` 
GROUP BY  `country` 
LIMIT 0 , 100) src;
```

Comment: Just change the group by to country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` **only by** `country`:

SELECT `country`, COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `Ipcount`
FROM `1799_visitors` 
GROUP BY `country`;

`GROUP BY ip` means that the `COUNT()` function is called once for each `ip` and thus will return 1 on very call. `GROUP BY country` calls the function `COUNT()` with all the `ip`-addresses for each country. Adding `DISTINCT` means that only the number of unique ip-addresses is counted, which is the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` `ip` as well as `country`

```
SELECT `country`, `ip`, COUNT(`ip`) AS `Ipcount`
FROM `1799_visitors` 
GROUP BY `country`, `ip`;
```

Results:

```
country ip  Ipcount
CZ  80.100.100.20   2
CZ  90.900.900.90   1
RU  55.555.555.55   1
```

See [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32592/2)

Comment: the same problem, but when I use just "order by country", it's working! :-D

Comment: @ТомасПетр, see edit in answer specially the fiddle demo

Comment: You don't understand me, i need number of visitors in countires. I do not need fact 2 IP addresses are the same.

Comment: am really confused with your comments now?